# Is it possible to send an SMS using a windows 8 tablet?

Tags: windows-8, sms

Now that there are some tablets with integral gsm modems, is there any support in the standard apps for sending or receiving SMS messages?

Comment: have you searched for sms in the app store?

Comment: Should we assume you mean a true SMS message, using the GSM modem, as opposed to using some Internet based gateway?

Comment: @ernie Yes, given I have the hardware present, with a SIM card (complete with an allowance) installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your Telco has a Windows 8 application, you will see the operator logo alongside the mobile network name (and connection type). Tapping that will prompt to install the operator's app. It is only these operator provided apps that *can* access SMS functionality, so at present this remains the only way.

In the case of [Three UK](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/three/9wzdncrdr440), their app only appears to support reception and reading of SMS messages, with no way to reply at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the major telecom providers have their own Windows 8 apps bundled with the tablets they sell. Such apps generally include SMS sending/receiving capabilities. Which is the telecom company providing your data connection? Look for their Windows 8 apps in the Store and install them.

Comment: Searching for my mobile provider (giffgaff) only brings back a (third party) app that does balance enquiries (via their web interface). My expectation was that the default Messaging app would be able to do it, perhaps after fiddling a setting here or there though.

Comment: The Messaging app is only a chat client.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Windows Store and search for "SMS", you will find a variety of free and for pay SMS capable applications.

You can do the same thing for "standard" apps with a search via your favorite search engine.

Comment: All of the results I saw were for sending SMS via an Internet gateway, not via the installed hardware.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - Most of the time somebody would roll out their own software for this.  Otherwise any Windows desktop application that allows for something like this can be used.

Comment: Well, the OS has native support for mobile broadband via the hardware, and it appears [there is an API for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh770508.aspx) - that document implies that only the device manufacturer or mobile operator could publish an app, and why I'd expect something like the Messaging app to have access (assuming that Microsoft would trust themselves to have access to the API), but I cannot see how I would enable the feature.